# Riesz Representation Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, riesz-representation-theorem

I am unfamiliar with Quantum Mechanics and all that stuff. I have recently studied Riesz Representation Theorem , I got to know that it justifies ket and the bra notation. Can anyone please give an intuitive explanation as to what ket and bra notation assumes and what is justified by the theorem. Thanks. Any references are also welcome.

Comment: Already answered: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569527/what-do-physicists-mean-with-this-bra-ket-notation.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla thanks a lot so does it mean that for every ket there is a function which when integrated gives the ket

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do physicists mean with this bra-ket notation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569527/what-do-physicists-mean-with-this-bra-ket-notation)